# Can be placed a footnote in a reference?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, footnotes

I am trying to place a footnote in a reference, see here an example:

```
\usepackage[stable,para,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,maxcitenames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
  \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
  #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a table:

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
  Col 1 & Col 2 \\
  \ref{sth:bla} \footnote{dksvnkjfs v df j} & \ref{sth:text}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

And here are some items:

\begin{description}
    \item[\textlabel{Something}{sth:bla}] \textlabel{The Text}{sth:text} \hfill \\
    Description!
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

But as you can see in the image the reference (in my document 37) does not appear:

[image]

Any option here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `longtable` instead of `tabular`. It should work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[stable,para,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,maxcitenames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
    \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
    \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
    #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    This is a table:

    \begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}{l|l}
            Col 1 & Col 2 \\
            \ref{sth:bla} \footnote{dksvnkjfs v df j} & \ref{sth:text}
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}

    And here are some items:

    \begin{description}
        \item[\textlabel{Something}{sth:bla}] \textlabel{The Text}{sth:text} \hfill \\
        Description!
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]